# Jar executable not playing wav, but playing midi and loading other resources

Tags: java, audio, wav, executable-jar

After I pack everything into my jar the sound stops working and if I use a `JOptionPane` to check the exception I get a null pointer. Weirdly enough it does work with midis.

I think I've tried everything I've seen proposed here but nothing seems to work.

Here's my project structure and my code (I'm calling it from Semaforo.java and I'm working with Linux). Any tips?

Code

[image: Code]

Structure

[image: Structure]

Comment: Have you tried the path `"/net/asiasmarch.semagoro/img/beep.wav"`?  Have you tried `getClass().getResourceAsString(...)` with both paths?

Comment: Yes, not exactly sure why but if I try that path I get an exception even when I run it from netbeans (I'm packing it from there too, not sure if important). And yes, I've also tried getClass()(etc) with both paths, same results. Really weird.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between the system classloader, which is what you're probably accessing by calling `getClassloader()` and the search path used by classes in your project.

The system classloader doesn't know how to do anything except load classes from `rt.jar` the JVM runtime.  Your classes know which Jar or file tree they were loaded from, and can load resources from those locations.

Anyway, removing `getClassloader()` and just calling `class.getResourceAsStream()` worked for me.

```
public class WavTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         InputStream ins = WavTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/Crash-Cymbal-1.wav");
         if( ins == null ) {
            System.err.println("Oops");
            return;
         }
         AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(ins);
         Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
         clip.open(audioInputStream);
         clip.start();
         Thread.sleep(2000);
   }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code so it works exactly like what you got but I got the exact same results : /


            `InputStream is;
            
            is = Semaforo.class.getResourceAsStream("/net/ausiasmarch/semaforo/img/beep.wav");
            if (is == null) {
                System.err.println("Oops");
                return;
            }
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is);
            
            sonido = AudioSystem.getClip();
            sonido.open(audioInputStream);
            sonido.start();`